# Can I use async method for Ninject bindings using ToMethod?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, ninject

I'm currently facing a problem with the asynchronous initialization of an object ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15907356/371804)). I'm using Ninject 3.0.1.10, and I want to achieve the following:

```
Kernel.Bind<IServiceProvider>().ToMethod(async ctx => await ServiceProvider.CreateAsync())
```

Now this thing doesn't compile, because async lambda expression returns a `Task<ServiceProvider>`, not a `ServiceProvider`. Is there any way to initialize objects asynchronously in Ninject? Maybe some workaround?

Comment: Have you tried `Task.Wait(/*...*/)`?

Comment: It will be synchronous then... But you're right, this asynchrony has to manifest itself somewhere. I guess, Kernel.Get() then should also be asynchronous. Is it possible in Ninject at all?

Comment: There is two ways how you can decouple injection from instanciation of IServiceProvider. The first is: inject Lazy<IServiceProvider>. This is supported by ninject, but means the IServiceProvider consumer then knows about it. The second is binding IServiceProvider to a proxy of the interface, where as the first call on the proxy will have to retrieve the actual instance (or perform it on a Lazy<IServiceProvider> again). However, note that ninject by default creates a proxy per type, not per instance. I have a work around for this. Tell me if you want me to post a complete solution.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit yes, please post your solution. I guess, some workaround wouldn't hurt, since there's no any answer on this question yet.

Answer (score 0):

As per your request i'm posting a solution which employs ninject.
I diverted slightly from your goals as the constructor is not performing the initialization but a method is. The method is called by the interceptor.
Async-Ctor is most likely possible by changing to an "interface proxy without target" (see http://docs.castleproject.org/Tools.Kinds-of-proxy-objects.ashx) and having the interceptor instanciate the object.

I also want to say that i believe async-initialization probably will provide more downsides than benefits. For example, it will be difficult to handle initialization exceptions, since any call on the interface may result in an initialization exception.

[image: Castle Dynamic Proxy + Interceptor which initializes target async]

`IFoo` is bound to `InterceptingProxyProvider : IProvider`. The provider instanciates `Foo`, all interceptors for `Foo`, and then creates and returns a castle dynamic proxy (`Proxy`).
This is what `Caller` receives when `IFoo` is being injected.
The `AsyncInitializationInterceptor` starts initialization of `Foo` in it's constructor.
Upon the first intercepted call, it waits for initialization to complete, then proceeds.
In case initialization fails with an exception, all further access to `IFoo` will result in the initialization exception being thrown.

On a further note, the ninject proxy extension creates an interceptor instance per target type. However, what we want is one interceptor instance per target instance. This is why i provided a custom implementation of binding & instanciation of the proxy & interceptors.

Here is the code, complete with integration tests which should show you how to use it:

- [github repo](https://github.com/BrunoJuchli/NinjectAsyncInitializationByInterception)
- [skydrive](http://sdrv.ms/18Ox0QC)

Comment: Could someone post the answer in code?. I'm unable to access both those urls, and I really would like to use an async lib with ninject.

Comment: The solution consists of quite a few source files. I could add them to the answer but it would mean you would have to add quite a lot of files to a solution/c# project. Instead, i could also upload it to another file hoster - in case there's one you can access? Just let me know.

Comment: It thats the case, perhaps a github repo would be best?. Most file sharing sites are blocked by IT here, but github is okay. Thank you for your response. I was also mainly after looking at the rough implementation. If it's a whole bunch of files maybe it is a github repo/nuget package instead :)

Comment: @user1570690 github Repo is now available: https://github.com/BrunoJuchli/NinjectAsyncInitializationByInterception