# Task.Run global Messagebox which blocks main window

Tags: c#, wpf

I run an awaited function in the constructor of my WPF application:

```
  Task.Run(async () =>
  {
      var r = await checkValidLicenseAsync(hardwareid);
      if (r == false)
        MessageBox.Show("no License.");
  }
```

The messagebox is not blocking my main window. I think this is because I run in a task? What is a workaround?

Comment: Invoke it on GUI thread. Throw an exception, handle it later and show the message box.

Comment: how can I invoke on the GUI thread?

Comment: Don't use task and use ShowDialog to keep focus

Comment: I can't run async functions in constructor

Comment: "how can I invoke on the GUI thread?" Please, Google that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you expecting from running this code as a task? It does not provide any advantage here. The possibly long running license validation is already being called with `await` making it non-UI blocking (unless its implementation is messed up).

To make the message box blocking, i.e. modal, simply write

```
  bool valid = await checkValidLicenseAsync(hardwareid); // non-blocking
  if (!valid) {
      MessageBox.Show("no License."); // blocking
  }
```

Assuming that this is the `System.Windows.MessageBox` and not its winforms pendant.

A possible approach is to use a factory method to return the object. Another one is to use an `AsyncLazy<T>` as described [here by Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15907606/880990)

See also:
- [Svick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8145668/880990) to [Can constructors be async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145479/can-constructors-be-async/8145668#8145668).

Comment: i run this code in a constructor. In a constructor I can't await a method

Comment: A constructor should always leave the object fully initialized. Also a constructor should never fail.

Comment: ok, I think I have to move my code to the loaded event of my main window

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can call an awaitable method into an constructor. Since constructor can't be added an async descriptor. You can call an delegate in an constructor. Just wrap your logic into a async delegate